# optimisation of a condition for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 2 datasets, one of which contains measurements of temperature at 30 min intervals

```
ordered.temp<-structure(list(time = structure(c(1385244720, 1385246520, 1385248320, 
1385250120, 1385251920, 1385253720, 1385255520, 1385257320, 1385259120, 
1385260920), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), temp = c(30.419, 
29.34, 28.965, 28.866, 28.891, 28.866, 28.692, 28.419, 28.122, 
27.85), hoboID = c(2392890L, 2392890L, 2392890L, 2392890L, 2392890L, 
2392890L, 2392890L, 2392890L, 2392890L, 2392890L)), .Names = c("time", 
"temp", "hoboID"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

, the other I created to be able to assign each measurement into 3-hour bins

```
df<-structure(list(start = structure(c(1385182800, 1385193600, 1385204400, 
1385215200, 1385226000, 1385236800, 1385247600, 1385258400, 1385269200, 
1385280000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), end = structure(c(1385193600, 
1385204400, 1385215200, 1385226000, 1385236800, 1385247600, 1385258400, 
1385269200, 1385280000, 1385290800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), b = 1:10), .Names = c("start", "end", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

For simplicity, I created a subset of the data, but in reality the temp dataframe is 460k rows long and growing bigger every year. I wrote a for loop to compare each line in `temp` with lines in `bin` and assign it the corresponding `b` value from the bin dataframe.

```
m <- length(ordered.temp$time)
b <- numeric(m)
n <- length(df$start)

for (i in 1:m){
  for (j in 1:n){
    if (df$start[j] < ordered.temp$time[i] & ordered.temp$time[i] <= df$end[j]){
      b[i] <- df$b[j]
      print(i/dim(ordered.temp)[1]*100)
    }
  }
}
```

Running this loop with 460k rows takes a very long time (i ran the loop for 1 minute and calculated that it would take ±277 hours to complete it. Therefore, it is imperative to speed this loop up or find alternative methods if this is not possible. I however have no idea how I achieve the desired result. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: If "bin" is sorted, `findInterval` should be useful. E.g. `bin$b[findInterval(temp$time, bin$start)]`. Depending on possible overlaps in "bin" you might have to confirm with something like `bin$end[findInterval(temp$time, bin$start)] > temp$time` etc.

Comment: What is `df` (is it bin) and `ordered.temp` (is it the same as `temp`)?

Comment: Indeed, bin = df, temp = ordered.temp.

Comment: `sapply(temp$time, function(x){bin$b[x >= bin$start & x <= bin$end]})` works if there's no overlap between intervals.

Comment: Thanks, it provides the same results for the sample data. However, does it work much faster than my for loop? How can I see the difference in speed?

Comment: @alistaire: if you reformulate your reply into an answer, I can mark this question as answered. If you could include some sort of code for status bar / process time i would highly appreciate this. Thank you:)

Comment: You can use `system.time` or the `microbenchmark` package to figure out what's fastest. In this case, my solution is about 12x faster than yours, but I've actually got to defer to @alexis_laz, whose solution above is 14x faster than mine, and 140x faster than yours. It makes sense; if there's a builtin function in base R, it's likely highly optimized in C or C++; `*apply` functions are usually faster than loops, but still loop; `for` loops in R are usually slow, though preallocating a result variable of the correct size can speed them up.

Comment: alistaire and alexis_laz, thank you both. I just tried alexis_laz's solution and i get instant results. awesome

Comment: @alistaire: what would happen to the proposed solutions if the intervals are overlapping?